# Meteor.startup not being called for Coffeescript files on server

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I have a few different files calling `Meteor.startup` on the server, both Javascript and Coffeescript. The Javascript ones are being ran but the Coffeescript ones are not. I'm running on Meteor 0.8.3, haven't tested on other versions yet. I'm debugging with just plain `console.log` statements on a locally running Meteor instance, JS is logging and CS is not.

This is the Coffeescript. None of the log statements below are shown on the server

```
Meteor.startup ->
  console.log "Hello coffee!"
  if Meteor.settings.AWS
    AWS.config.update
      accessKeyId: Meteor.settings.AWS.accessKeyId
      secretAccessKey: Meteor.settings.AWS.secretAccessKey
      console.log "AWS settings loaded"
  else
    console.warn "AWS settings missing"
```

And the compiled Javascript, which runs correctly on its own as a separate file:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  console.log("Hello javascript!");
  if (Meteor.settings.AWS) {
    return AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: Meteor.settings.AWS.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: Meteor.settings.AWS.secretAccessKey
    }, console.log("AWS settings loaded"));
  } else {
    return console.warn("AWS settings missing");
  }
});
```

Comment: can you show the coffescript code? Also, have you verified that the js translation of your coffeescript indeed calls `Meteor.startup`?

Comment: Added, and yes it does

Comment: The coffeescript file isn't only executed on the client? What's the path to the coffeescript file? You have added the `coffeescript` package?

Comment: Haha, wow yeah, didn't have the coffeescript package added. That would do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have the `coffeescript` package added. That would do it.